# Return Value from a function in a utils file to the state in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to refactor my functions to modular them in a clean way. I need to get the return value from my functions and assign them each to an state in my component. the functions already invoke and log the value in the console( i am using axios). but it doesn't set state and I cannot render the value to the screen.

```
export const getWalletBalance = token => {
  let Amount = '';
  console.log('get wallet balance');
  axios
    .get(`${Routes.walletBalance}`, {headers: {token: token}})
    .then(async res => {
      console.log(res);
      return await (Amount = res.data.value.response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return console.log(err.response);
    });
  return Amount;
};
```

and this is the setstate

```
            this.setState({Amount: getWalletBalance(token)});
```

should I use async/await?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are conflating async programming patterns async/await and promises while doing nothing with the resolved values.

Because of how async programming works, you return the empty string before your promise ever has a chance to resolve.

The order of execution is as follows:

1. `let Amount = ''`
2. Promise starts to perform asynchronously
3. Value of empty string `''` is returned

You also have an incorrect usage of async/await.

#### Service

```
export const getWalletBalance = token => {
  return axios
    .get(`${Routes.walletBalance}`, { headers: { token: token } })
    .then(res => {
      return res.data.value.response;
    });
};
```

And below, you can use either the promises implementation or the async/await implementation.

#### Promises implementation

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      token: '<token>',
      Amount: null
    };
  }

  // Implementation with promises
  componentDidMount() {
    getWalletBalance(this.state.token)
      .then((balance) => {
        this.setState({ Amount: balance });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.state.Amount}
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Async/await implementation

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      token: '<token>',
      Amount: null
    };
  }

  // Implementation with async/await
  async componentDidMount() {
    const balance = await getWalletBalance(this.state.token)
    this.setState({ Amount: balance });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.state.Amount}
      </p>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export const getWalletBalance = token => {

  return axios
    .get(`${Routes.walletBalance}`, {headers: {token: token}})
    .then(async res => {
      return res.data.value.response; // return your amount direct
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return 0; // return your amount direct
      console.log(err.response);
    });
};
```

you can access it like

put this call in async function so, you can use await

```
let Amount = await getWalletBalance(token);
this.setState({ Amount });
```